# AngularJS - ng-click is calling multiple times

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and have been learning it from W3Schools. My issue is that `ng-click` is not working properly. It's calling repeatedly. If I click on the element with `ng-click` once it calls the function once. If I click it again it calls the function twice. If I continue clicking the button the function is called as many times as I've clicked the element before.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h1 id="h12" ng-click="changeName()" style="cursor:pointer;">{{firstname}}</h1>
  </div>

  <script>
    var count = 0;

    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {


      $scope.firstname = "John";
      $scope.changeName = function() {
        var h12 = document.getElementById("h12").innerHTML;
        alert(count);
        if (count == 0) {
          $scope.firstname = "Nelly";

          changeNGClick(h12);
          count++;
        } else {


          count++;
          var x = "";
          var div1 = document.getElementById("h12");
          var align = div1.getAttribute("data-v");
          alert(align);

          $scope.firstname = align;
          changeNGClick(h12);

        }


      }
      return false;

    });

    function compile(element) {
      var el = angular.element(element);
      $scope = el.scope();
      $injector = el.injector();
      $injector.invoke(function($compile) {
        $compile(el)($scope)
      })
    }

    function changeNGClick(v) {
      var el = document.getElementById("h12");
      el.setAttribute("data-v", v);
      compile(el);
    }
  </script>

  <p>Click on the header to run the "changeName" function.</p>

  <p>This example demonstrates how to use the controller to change model data.</p>

</body>

</html>
```

This is how the code will work. When I click the header which has the text John then it will change to display Nelly. If you click it again it should change back to John. The value will be saved on the `<h1>` tags `data-v`. I would also appreciate another way of doing this if you have any suggestions.

Comment: you are compiling the element over and over. this causes that your <h1> element gets the ng-click function again (and again..)

Comment: Is there any other method to append data on h1 tag; let me know

Comment: Thanks a lot I have got it use javascript Dom i.e. to set attribute document.getElementById("h12").setAttribute("data-v", h12);

Comment: I highly discourage you for doing DOM manipulation inside angular controller. This can be easily achievable by using several combination of angular directives like `ng-model`, `ng-click`

Comment: But how to get inner html in angular js.....